# How to load items with SuiteScript Purchase Orders?

Tags: netsuite, purchase-order, suitescript

Friends'm working with NetSuite and SuiteScript. I can save a purchase order running the script and also charge Purchase Orders created, but when I bring returns data item value as a null value, and I need to get the id of the item.

The result gives me the log NetSuite is:

Purchase Order ID: 3706 Vendor ID: 144 Item ID: null Trandate: 06/08/2015 Form: Standard Purchase Order Currency: Peso CL

this happens all Purchase Orders and obviously if you have an item attached.

function to load javascript to use Purchase Order is as follows:

```
function loadPurchaseOrder(){

nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','loadPurchaseOrder', 'Entra a funcion loadPurchaseOrder');    

//se aplican filtros para la busqueda del objeto  
var filters= new Array();
filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('purchaseorder',null,'isnotempty');
filters[1] = new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'T');

//seleccion de los campos que se quieren extraer
var columns = new Array();    
columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('item');
columns[1] = new nlobjSearchColumn('entity');
columns[2] = new nlobjSearchColumn('trandate');
columns[3] = new nlobjSearchColumn('customform');
columns[4] = new nlobjSearchColumn('currency');
columns[5] = new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid');

var results = nlapiSearchRecord('purchaseorder',null,filters,columns);

var out = "";
if(results != null ){

    for(var i=0; i< results.length; i++){

        var purchaseOrder = results[i];
        var idItem = purchaseOrder.getValue('item');                        
        var idVendor = purchaseOrder.getValue('entity');
        var trandate = purchaseOrder.getValue('trandate');
        var form = purchaseOrder.getText('customform');
        var currency = purchaseOrder.getText('currency');
        var idPurchaseOrder = purchaseOrder.getText('internalid');

        out = " ID Purchase Order: " + idPurchaseOrder + " ID Vendor: " + idVendor + " ID Item: " + idItem
              + " Trandate: " + trandate + " Form: " + form + " Currency: " + currency;

        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','purchaseOrderCargada', out);

    }
} 

return out;
```

}

If someone could please help me. Greetings!

pd:

I've also tried:

var idItem = nlapiGetLineItemField ('item', 'item');

and it does not work = /

Comment: Which item id you want to pull  @Chris2141? Did you mean the line items included in that PO ?

Comment: I want to show only the number of ID or associated items to Purchase Order, plus all the other data contained Purchase Order @Rockstar

Comment: I din't see a way to get the line items in PO without loading the record. You can't just pull them defining search columns. Those are line items not body field items. Inorder to get them you need to load the record and have to use `(nlobjReferenceObject of type PO).getLineItemValue('item','item',index);`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try with what you propose. Greetings! @Rockstar =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is maybe a longer answer than you're expecting, but here we go.

NetSuite divides Transaction records (Purchase Order is a type of Transaction) into Body and Line Item fields. When you do a Transaction search that includes `mainline = 'T'`, you are telling NetSuite to only retrieve Body field data. The `item` field, however, is a Line Item field, so NetSuite will not return any data for it. That's why `idItem` is `null`.

Understanding the behaviour of the `mainline` filter is crucial to Transaction searches. Basically, it goes like this:

- `mainline = 'T'` will only return body field data, so it will return exactly one search result per Transaction
- `mainline = 'F'` will only return line item data, so it will return one search result for every *line item* on matching Transactions
- `mainline` not specified will return both body field and line data, so it will return one result for each transaction itself plus one result for each line on each transaction.

Here's a concrete example. Let's say that there is only one Purchase Order in the system that matches all of your other search filters (besides `mainline`), and that Purchase Order has three items on it. This is how the search results will change based on the `mainline` filter:

- If `mainline = 'T'` then you will get exactly one result for the Purchase Order, and you will only get data for Search Columns that are Body fields.
- If `mainline = 'F'` then you will get exactly *three* results, one for each line item, and all of your Search Columns will contain data whether they are Body or Line fields
- If `mainline` is not specified then you will get exactly *four* results, one of them will only contain data for Body fields, and the other three will contain both Line and Body data

It's difficult to advise on exactly how you should change your search as I do not know what you plan to do with these search results.

Comment: Nice Description : ) @egrubaugh360

Comment: Thank you very much for the description, did not know and now I have much more clear. I need to do is list the purchase orders with their respective fields nothing more than that, is why I need also items that are associated with each of the existing Purchase Order. There is a way to do this ?? Thanks for the help. Greetings!

Comment: @Rockstar you can help me ?

Comment: Thank you for this explanation @erictgrubaugh