# Scripting search in NetSuite not working as expected

Tags: javascript, search, scripting, netsuite

I tried a search script in NetSuite and the problem I'm having is that the search is getting several results despite I put the order number in the transaction table search. If I do the same search by the IU I just get 1 result which is the correct one.

*The script is*

```js
var filters = new Array();

filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('item', null, 'is', 'ITEM123');
filters[1] = new nlobjSearchFilter('type', null, 'is', 'SalesOrd');
filters[2] = new nlobjSearchFilter('companyname', 'customer', 'contains', 'CustomerName');
filters[3] = new nlobjSearchFilter('number', null, 'is', 'ORDER9887');


var columns = new Array();
columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('item');
columns[1] = new nlobjSearchColumn('type');
columns[2] = new nlobjSearchColumn('name','item');
columns[3] = new nlobjSearchColumn('companyname','customer');
columns[4] = new nlobjSearchColumn('number');


var searchResults = nlapiSearchRecord('transaction', null, filters, columns);
var values = 'TOTAL RESULTS: ' + searchResults.length;
if(searchResults != null)
{
  for( i = 0 ; i<  searchResults.length ; i++)
  {
   values = values + '\r\nITEM ' +  searchResults[i].getValue(columns[0]) + 
            '\r\nTYPE ' +  searchResults[i].getValue(columns[1]) +
            '\r\nITEM NAME ' + searchResults[i].getValue(columns[2]) +
            '\r\nCOMPANY NAME ' + searchResults[i].getValue(columns[3]) +
            '\r\nTRANSACTION NUMBER ' + searchResults[i].getValue(columns[4]); 
  }
  alert(values);
}
```

So it doesn't make much sense to me, it's suppose that filters are implicitly with an **AND** operator.

Is there any clue which I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Pablo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When searching transactions, you need to understand and use the `mainline` filter to adjust the results you want. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929239/how-to-load-items-with-suitescript-purchase-orders/31930323#31930323) for a more detailed explanation.

Unfortunately, I cannot explain why you are getting different results for the exact same criteria between the UI and the script. I would need to see the UI search as well to troubleshoot that.

You are correct that search filters provided this way are always with an `AND` operator. You can instead use filter expressions to explicitly state the logical operator. See the NetSuite Help document titled *Filtering a Search* for examples of filter expressions.

Using filter expressions and the mainline filter, I might write your search something like:

```js
// Filter expression syntax
var filters = [
    ['item', 'is', 'ITEM123'], 'and',
    ['type', 'is', 'SalesOrd'], 'and',
    ['mainline', 'is', 'F'], 'and', // mainline=F gives me only line item results
    ['customer.companyname', 'contains', 'CustomerName'], 'and',
    ['number', 'is', 'ORDER9887']
];

var columns = [
    new nlobjSearchColumn('item'),
    new nlobjSearchColumn('type'),
    new nlobjSearchColumn('name','item'),
    new nlobjSearchColumn('companyname','customer'),
    new nlobjSearchColumn('number')
];

// I always default my search results to [] to avoid the null check later
var searchResults = (nlapiSearchRecord('transaction', null, filters, columns) || []);

// Logging to console assuming client script, otherwise use nlapiLogExecution
console.log('TOTAL RESULTS: ' + searchResults.length);

// I prefer using Array.map or Array.forEach when iterating over arrays in SuiteScript
var resultString = searchResults.map(
    function (result) { // Change each result to its String representation
        return 'ITEM ' + result.getValue('item') + 
            '\r\nTYPE ' +  result.getValue('type') +
            '\r\nITEM NAME ' + result.getValue('name', 'item') +
            '\r\nCOMPANY NAME ' + result.getValue('companyname','customer') +
            '\r\nTRANSACTION NUMBER ' + result.getValue('number'); 
    }
).join("\r\n"); // Join all of the result strings with a newline

console.log(resultString);
```

Comment: Hi Eric I tried your changes and I got 70 results, it is supposed I should get only 1 since we are putting the order number.
Is there anything else to add to filter out results?

Comment: I suspect the search is ignoring `['number', 'is', 'ORDER9887']`. The clause should be `['tranid', 'is', 'ORDER9887']`. `number` is an integer field  so if you knew the base number of the transaction you'd use `['number', 'equalto', '9887']`

Comment: Also you probably want to add ` and ['cogs', 'is', 'F']`

Comment: the one that worked was ['tranid', 'is', 'ORDER9887']